# DataRow.SetColumnError(Int32, String) ignores Int32 value and always uses zero

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

Okay, this is doing my head in.  I'm calling SetColumnError() on a DataRow object that has 20 columns, but no matter which ColumnIndex I use it sets the error text on column 0.  The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15s33fe9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) makes it plainly clear that the error text is supposed to be set on the column that the ColumnIndex provides.

I'm trying to set error text on columns 1 and 2 (I normally use constants when doing this, I have just used the integers in this example code for simplicity).  Why does the error text appear on column 0 and what should I be doing to get the text to show on columns 1 and 2?  I'm not receiving IndexOutOfRangeException.

Here is the code I'm having trouble with.

```
Public Sub ValidateRows()

    For Each dgvRow As DataGridViewRow In Me.DataGridView1.Rows
        If dgvRow.DataBoundItem IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim rowView As DataRowView = dgvRow.DataBoundItem
            Dim rowData As MyDataSet.DocumentRow = rowView.Row
            rowData.ClearErrors()
            If rowData.Revision = rowData.Revision_old Then
                rowData.SetColumnError(1, "You must change the revision")
            End If
            If rowData.InternalRevision = rowData.InternalRevision_old Then
                rowData.SetColumnError(2, "You must change the internal revision")
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm beginning to think that it is related to interference from a base class that handles the DataGridView.CellFormatting event.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think the number of the column must be of the type "DataColumn".

Comment: That's one possible overload.  There are three overloads: SetColumnError(DataColumn, String); SetColumnError(Int32, String); SetColumnError(String, String).  I'm using the Int32 overload.

Comment: And are you sure the row you're trying to access has more than one column? Maybe you could debug the program and check that.

Comment: I tried referencing a column index above 19 and it threw the IndexOutOfRangeException exception as expected.